# RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cpu

Tags: pytorch, gpu, torch, torchvision

I am implementing nn.DataParallel class in code and i encapsulate all my models in this class. It gives an error ambiguous error.

**Class Code**

```
import time
import os
import argparse

import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.optim as optim
import torch.optim.lr_scheduler as LS
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.autograd import Variable
import torch.utils.data as data
from torchvision import transforms

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    '--batch-size', '-N', type=int, default=16, help='batch size')
parser.add_argument(
    '--train', '-f', required=True, type=str, help='folder of training images')
parser.add_argument(
    '--max-epochs', '-e', type=int, default=4, help='max epochs')
parser.add_argument('--lr', type=float, default=0.0005, help='learning rate')
parser.add_argument('--cuda', '-g', action='store_true', help='enables cuda')
parser.add_argument(
    '--iterations', type=int, default=16, help='unroll iterations')
parser.add_argument('--checkpoint', type=int, help='unroll iterations')
args = parser.parse_args()

## load 32x32 patches from images
import dataset

train_transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

train_set = dataset.ImageFolder(root=args.train, transform=train_transform)

train_loader = data.DataLoader(
    dataset=train_set, batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

print('total images: {}; total batches: {}'.format(
    len(train_set), len(train_loader)))

## load networks on GPU
import network

print("Devices are ", torch.cuda.device_count())

torch.cuda.set_device(1)

encoder = nn.DataParallel(network.EncoderCell(), device_ids = [1, 3])
binarizer = nn.DataParallel(network.Binarizer(), device_ids = [1, 3])
decoder = nn.DataParallel(network.DecoderCell(), device_ids = [1, 3])

solver = optim.Adam(
    [
        {
            'params': encoder.parameters()
        },
        {
            'params': binarizer.parameters()
        },
        {
            'params': decoder.parameters()
        },
    ],
    lr=args.lr)


def resume(epoch=None):
    if epoch is None:
        s = 'iter'
        epoch = 0
    else:
        s = 'epoch'

    encoder.load_state_dict(
        torch.load('checkpoint/encoder_{}_{:08d}.pth'.format(s, epoch)))
    binarizer.load_state_dict(
        torch.load('checkpoint/binarizer_{}_{:08d}.pth'.format(s, epoch)))
    decoder.load_state_dict(
        torch.load('checkpoint/decoder_{}_{:08d}.pth'.format(s, epoch)))


def save(index, epoch=True):
    if not os.path.exists('checkpoint'):
        os.mkdir('checkpoint')

    if epoch:
        s = 'epoch'
    else:
        s = 'iter'

    torch.save(encoder.state_dict(), 'checkpoint/encoder_{}_{:08d}.pth'.format(
        s, index))

    torch.save(binarizer.state_dict(),
               'checkpoint/binarizer_{}_{:08d}.pth'.format(s, index))

    torch.save(decoder.state_dict(), 'checkpoint/decoder_{}_{:08d}.pth'.format(
        s, index))


# resume()

scheduler = LS.MultiStepLR(solver, milestones=[3, 10, 20, 50, 100], gamma=0.5)

last_epoch = 0
if args.checkpoint:
    resume(args.checkpoint)
    last_epoch = args.checkpoint
    scheduler.last_epoch = last_epoch - 1

for epoch in range(last_epoch + 1, args.max_epochs + 1):

    scheduler.step()

    for batch, data in enumerate(train_loader):
        batch_t0 = time.time()

        ## init lstm state
        encoder_h_1 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 256, 8, 8).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 256, 8, 8).cuda()))
        # print(encoder_h_1)
        encoder_h_2 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 4, 4).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 4, 4).cuda()))
        encoder_h_3 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 2, 2).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 2, 2).cuda()))

        decoder_h_1 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 2, 2).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 2, 2).cuda()))
        decoder_h_2 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 4, 4).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 512, 4, 4).cuda()))
        decoder_h_3 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 256, 8, 8).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 256, 8, 8).cuda()))
        decoder_h_4 = (Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 128, 16, 16).cuda()),
                       Variable(torch.zeros(data.size(0), 128, 16, 16).cuda()))

        patches = Variable(data.cuda())

        solver.zero_grad()

        losses = []

        res = patches - 0.5

        bp_t0 = time.time()

        for _ in range(args.iterations):
            encoded, encoder_h_1, encoder_h_2, encoder_h_3 = encoder(
                res, encoder_h_1, encoder_h_2, encoder_h_3)

            codes = binarizer(encoded)

            output, decoder_h_1, decoder_h_2, decoder_h_3, decoder_h_4 = decoder(
                codes, decoder_h_1, decoder_h_2, decoder_h_3, decoder_h_4)

            res = res - output
            losses.append(res.abs().mean())

        bp_t1 = time.time()

        loss = sum(losses) / args.iterations
        loss.backward()

        solver.step()

        batch_t1 = time.time()

        print(
            '[TRAIN] Epoch[{}]({}/{}); Loss: {:.6f}; Backpropagation: {:.4f} sec; Batch: {:.4f} sec'.
                format(epoch, batch + 1,
                       len(train_loader), loss.data, bp_t1 - bp_t0, batch_t1 -
                       batch_t0))
        print(('{:.4f} ' * args.iterations +
               '\n').format(*[l.data for l in losses]))

        index = (epoch - 1) * len(train_loader) + batch

        ## save checkpoint every 500 training steps
        if index % 500 == 0:
            save(0, False)

    save(epoch)
```

**TraceBack**.

```
total images: 9271670; total batches: 579480
Devices are  4
/data1/khawar/khawar/Conference/CVPR/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.py:82: UserWarning: Detected call of `lr_scheduler.step()` before `optimizer.step()`. In PyTorch 1.1.0 and later, you should call them in the opposite order: `optimizer.step()` before `lr_scheduler.step()`.  Failure to do this will result in PyTorch skipping the first value of the learning rate schedule.See more details at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate
  "https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/optim.html#how-to-adjust-learning-rate", UserWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 152, in <module>
    res, encoder_h_1, encoder_h_2, encoder_h_3)
  File "/data1/khawar/khawar/Conference/CVPR/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 547, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/khawar/khawar/Conference/CVPR/lib/python3.5/site-packages/torch/nn/parallel/data_parallel.py", line 146, in forward
    "them on device: {}".format(self.src_device_obj, t.device))
RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:1 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cpu
```

Comment: some of your tensors are set to run with cuda, some not. You cant perform calculations with tensors which are not on the same deivce. So check every tensor you got at set it to the device you want

Comment: Yes, How can i convert this code to completely nn.DataParallel class? I have four gpu. This code works fine on 1 gpu but it consumes 6 days for one epoch

Answer (score 1):

Move DataParallel modules to CUDA memory:

```
encoder = nn.DataParallel(network.EncoderCell(), device_ids = [1, 3]).cuda()
binarizer = nn.DataParallel(network.Binarizer(), device_ids = [1, 3]).cuda()
decoder = nn.DataParallel(network.DecoderCell(), device_ids = [1, 3]).cuda()
```